# How can I remove the double timestamps in journald logs for tezos?

Tags: setup, logging

I have set up my tezos services to be controlled by systemd using [etomknudsen's scripts](https://github.com/etomknudsen/tezos-baking). The output from those services gets logged by journald with double timestamps since both the tezos applications and journald itself each add a timestamp. For tezos-node a typical log line looks like this:

```
Mar 18 08:44:58 baker.example.com tezos-node[27442]: Mar 18 08:44:58 - validator.chain(1): Pushed: 2019-03-18T13:44:58Z, Treated: 2019-03-18T13:44:58Z, Completed: 2019-03-18T13:44:58Z
```

Can I change the configuration so that only one timestamp appears in each log line?

Answer (score 2):

For the tezos-node service it is possible to remove the timestamp using a tezos-node configuration with the following additional parameter at the top level:

```
 "log": { "template": "$(section): $(message)" },
```

That results in log output like this:

```
Mar 18 09:41:43 baker.example.com tezos-node[27537]: validator.chain(1): Pushed: 2019-03-18T14:41:43Z, Treated: 2019-03-18T14:41:43Z, Completed: 2019-03-18T14:41:43Z
```

Edit: **As of octez v18.0, the above does not work**, resulting instead in a fatal error about "Invalid configuration file: Unexpected object field template"

Comment: I have not found a similar solution for tezos-baker and tezos-endorser. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Code [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/eb3476228524d94267b355951cececf3ea50300f/src/lib_client_base_unix/client_main_run.ml#L65) and [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/eb3476228524d94267b355951cececf3ea50300f/src/lib_stdlib_unix/logging_unix.ml#L181) suggest that the client would need a patch to accept a template (from config file? env var?). As a hack, one could just patch [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/eb3476228524d94267b355951cececf3ea50300f/src/lib_stdlib/logging.ml#L251)...